# IIS7 Simple http authentication

Tags: iis-7, passwords

I've seen this question before but can't find a good answer for it.

I have an ASP.NET website using `FormsAuthentication`, it has some anonymous and protected parts. Now I publish this on a development machine connected to the Internet, I only want testers to have access to this website. So outsiders cannot see anything of the website, not even the formsauth login screen.

What I want is like a `.htaccess` popup that asks for a username/password, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Helicon Ape free](http://www.helicontech.com/download-ape.htm) and put [.htacces and .htpasswd files](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/htaccess-generator.shtml) in the root of the site you are trying to protect.